# Using pyspark, how to expand a column containing a variable map to new columns in a DataFrame while keeping other columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame

```
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+---+
|asset|signals                                           |ts |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+---+
|2    |[D -> 1100, F -> 3000]                            |6  |
|1    |[D -> 500, System.Date -> 340]                    |5  |
|1    |[B -> 100, E -> 900, System.Date -> 310]          |4  |
|1    |[B -> 110, C -> 200, System.Date -> 320]          |3  |
|1    |[A -> 330, B -> 120, C -> 210, D -> 410, E -> 100]|2  |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+---+
```

I need to project the column:'signals' with key-values to multiple columns as follows:

```
+-----+---+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|asset|ts |System.Date|F   |E   |B   |D   |C   |A   |
+-----+---+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|2    |6  |null       |3000|null|null|1100|null|null|
|1    |5  |340        |null|null|null|500 |null|null|
|1    |4  |310        |null|900 |100 |null|null|null|
|1    |3  |320        |null|null|110 |null|200 |null|
|1    |2  |null       |null|100 |120 |410 |210 |330 |
+-----+---+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

So here is the example:

```
d = [{'asset': '2', 'ts': 6, 'signals':{'F': '3000','D':'1100'}}, 
     {'asset': '1', 'ts': 5, 'signals':{'System.Date': '340','D':'500'}}, 
     {'asset': '1', 'ts': 4, 'signals':{'System.Date': '310', 'B': '100', 'E':'900'}}, 
     {'asset': '1', 'ts': 3, 'signals':{'System.Date': '320', 'B': '110','C':'200'}},
      {'asset': '1', 'ts': 2, 'signals':{'A': '330', 'B': '120','C':'210','D':'410','E':'100'}}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d)
```

I can extract all the possible keys and achieve my objective as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as spfn
# the following takes too long (WANT-TO-AVOID)
all_signals = (df
    .select(spfn.explode("signals"))
    .select("key")
    .distinct()
    .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
    .collect())
print(all_signals)
exprs = [spfn.col("signals").getItem(k).alias(k) for k in all_signals]

df1 = df.select(spfn.col('*'),*exprs).drop('signals')

df1.show(truncate=False)

['System.Date', 'F', 'E', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'A']
+-----+---+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|asset|ts |System.Date|F   |E   |B   |D   |C   |A   |
+-----+---+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|2    |6  |null       |3000|null|null|1100|null|null|
|1    |5  |340        |null|null|null|500 |null|null|
|1    |4  |310        |null|900 |100 |null|null|null|
|1    |3  |320        |null|null|110 |null|200 |null|
|1    |2  |null       |null|100 |120 |410 |210 |330 |
+-----+---+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

but I was wondering if there is a way to use the following but don't know how to keep existing columns:

```
df2 = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.signals))
df2.show(truncate=False)
+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+
|A   |B   |C   |D   |E   |F   |System.Date|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+
|null|null|null|1100|null|1000|null       |
|null|null|null|500 |null|null|340        |
|null|100 |null|null|900 |null|310        |
|null|110 |200 |null|null|null|320        |
|330 |120 |210 |410 |100 |null|null       |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+
```

The step above (labeled WANT-TO-AVOID) to get all keys takes a long time while the "spark.read.json" seems much faster.
So again, is there an easier and faster way to expand the map column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with **`read.json`** to get your desired columns. **`(spark2.4+)`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1=df.withColumn("signals", F.map_concat("signals", F.create_map(F.lit("asset"),"asset",F.lit("ts"),"ts")))

df2 = spark.read.json(df1.rdd.map(lambda r: r.signals))

df2.show()

#+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+-----+---+
#|   A|   B|   C|   D|   E|   F|System.Date|asset| ts|
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+-----+---+
#|null|null|null|1100|null|3000|       null|    2|  6|
#|null|null|null| 500|null|null|        340|    1|  5|
#|null| 100|null|null| 900|null|        310|    1|  4|
#|null| 110| 200|null|null|null|        320|    1|  3|
#| 330| 120| 210| 410| 100|null|       null|    1|  2|
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+-----+---+
```

Comment: It does achieve the final objective but feels like a bit of a hack :) . So you made my other columns part of the map which I will have to modify because i don't know all the possible columns. Nevertheless, i will test its performance. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: yeah u can dynamically add all other columns to your create_map as you have in ur other question.. basically putting all cols in the map col so read.json can expand it. n yes def it is a hack because the most common way to do it would be to get keys first using collect(as u shown), and if thats a constraint then we can only use explode, groupby and pivot which will be very expensive. another way would be use convert maptype to structtype but its messy and probably inefficient, the read.json way was interesting to me because I hadnt studied that execution yet

Comment: I am accepting this as a direct answer to my question. Having done the performance test, the original code runs faster!

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation of getting the unique key values was slow, but this should be faster:

```py
keys_df = df.select(F.explode(F.map_keys(F.col("signals")))).distinct()
keys = list(map(lambda row: row[0], keys_df.collect()))
key_cols = list(map(lambda f: F.col("signals").getItem(f).alias(str(f)), keys))
final_cols = [F.col("asset"), F.col("ts")] + key_cols
df.select(final_cols).show()
```

```
+-----+---+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|asset| ts|System.Date|   F|   E|   B|   D|   C|   A|
+-----+---+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    2|  6|       null|3000|null|null|1100|null|null|
|    1|  5|        340|null|null|null| 500|null|null|
|    1|  4|        310|null| 900| 100|null|null|null|
|    1|  3|        320|null|null| 110|null| 200|null|
|    1|  2|       null|null| 100| 120| 410| 210| 330|
+-----+---+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: nice one, ur def slightly speeding up the map/driver side of the computation(list comp vs map) but in my opinion the bottleneck is not on driver side(for e.g distinct() on an exploded dataframe)